# Module not specified?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I have recently started learning android development, and I just built an app that changes color and text based on pushing buttons and gestures. It ran fine on my phone (Yay!), but then on my second run, an error occurred. When hitting the "run" button, an edit configurations window opened up:

[image]

I also noticed, that on the side where my project tree should be is this instead:

[image]

I don't think there is an issue in the code because it was running fine before, but I would be happy to post the code if needed.

**Also**

I dont know if this was the reason, but i'll include this anyway, I tried changing the name of my project, but it wouldn't work, but I changed it back. I included this in my question because that's literally the only thing I did before this error occured.

**Thank you so much** for helping out a fellow programmer, I really appreciate it. I have been looking at many other forums (for some hours) about this topic, but still couldn't trouble shoot this problem. It seems kind of odd that it was working first, and then it just randomly stopped working. I cant wait for your response!

Here is the dropdown for Module:
[image]
As you can see, that is the only option.

Comment: What happens when you select a module from the dropdown at the top?

Comment: try clean and rebuild the project

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks for the response, but that is the only option in the dropdown. <no module> is the only option. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin How do I clean the project? Sorry i am a newbie, but when I rebuild the project, the error stays the same.  Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I have put a screen shot in my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you are opening the project as android gradle project ?
Try to import the program not open it

Comment: What does it mean to import the program and not to open it. Sorry, I am new at android, I would really appreciate it if you told me the steps to take in order to import the program as android gradle project. Thanks :)

Comment: From file menu in the top left choose new project then import project and show it the location of your project.

Comment: That usually happens because the gradle info of the project isn't complete (gradle is the build system for android projects in android studio), so when you open it android studio won't understand the project structure , but importing it will create and fix the gradle info needed for the project.

Comment: Okay, I have marked you as best answer. Could you explain what importing it does a little more, also will I run into this problem a lot, and how do I fix it (without importing) next time?

Comment: If nothing changes gradle files in the project, it's not supposed to happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91331/discussion-between-ahmed-gamal-and-rich).